# Remove entire block of text from a string if it matches a format

Tags: python, string

In my text data , i have text based embedding for images of the format

```
x = "[cid:image001.jpg@01D67C81.30D4DBD0] [cid:image004.jpg@01D67C84.31D4DBD3] Regards, John"
```

I was using the startswith method , but to no avail.

```
text = ' '.join(x for x in s.split() if not x.startswith('[cid:'))
```

Then i used the regex

```
cid:(.*?)$(.*?)
```

it matched and grouped into index 1 , everything after the cid:
what i was intending to do was get the out put only as `Regards, John`

So i was trying to create something in the line of a regular expression based negation with the condition being anything starting with "[cid: " upto the first whitespace.

Comment: I think your `startswith` code should have worked. What result are you expecting, what did you get instead?

Comment: `re.sub(r'\[cid:.*?\]', '', x)`

Comment: Sorry. I didn't remove s with x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled your code with only changing `x for x in s.split()` to `x for x in x.split()` because I didn't know what `s` was and it worked. I didn't even need to use your regex. It worked fine giving the output `Regards, John`.

The code I compiled is:

```
x = "[cid:image001.jpg@01D67C81.30D4DBD0] [cid:image004.jpg@01D67C84.31D4DBD3] Regards, John" 
text = ' '.join(x for x in x.split() if not x.startswith('[cid:'))
print(text)
```

Printed: `Regards, John`